# Error in IE 8 Standards Mode

Tags: internet-explorer, kendo-ui

When using **Kendo UI v2014.2.1008** in our web pages, with **Chrome**, and **IE 10** there is no problem. However with ***IE8 Standards mode*** UI controls does not render correctly. That's the case for viewing the page in IE8 without any development tool or so.

When the user user enters an input to the multiselect javascript error below is thrown, which is also IE 8 standards mode specific.:

SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 3 character 20616

Regards

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors when the page is loaded? (before the user would do anything, just loading the page). In what way to the controls render incorrectly? Are they just styled wrong, or do they not initialize at all?

Comment: There is no javascript error when the page is loaded. Kendo controls in the page are rendered with curved edges in Chrome or IE 10 which is the the normal behaviour. However when IE8 controls are rendered as if they are normal HTML controls. Controls are not just styled wrong, when you start a datasource binding event from kendomultisource control above mentioned javascript error is thrown: Unexpected call to method or property access (jquery-1.11.1.min.js, line 3 character 20616) İn that line : b.appendChild(a) throws this error actually.

Comment: I wonder if there is some Javascript either in Kendo or a custom template that is missing a semi-colon or a comma or something. The IE8 JS engine is really picky. Also, IE8 doesn't support border-radius, so that might explain the rounded corner styling.

Comment: Actually I checked my javascript code and HTML Markup with jshint, but that didn't help. Styling is not a problem actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this link **Georgi Krustev** gave the answer

http://www.telerik.com/forums/error-in-ie-8-standards-mode#u8QKlaud8k6r7pSSIso8qQ

HTML **select** should be used for the **Multiselect** control.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/browsers-support

Suggests:

> Internet Explorer compatibility modes are not supported. These modes can exhibit different behavior and rendering bugs, compared to the browser versions they emulate. It is highly recommended to use IE's Edge mode via META tag or HTTP header.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer. However that made no sense.

Comment: This explains the meta tags that IE8 checks for what mode to set. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx

Comment: Changing the mode with meta tags did not help at all. I tried all the modes : (